# Biopython cannot download .PDB files now

Tags: python, biopython

I am having trouble with Biopyhton. I used this code to download a set of proteins

```
from Bio.PDB import *
from biopandas.pdb import PandasPdb
import Bio
from Bio.PDB import PDBList
ppdb0 = []
ppdb1 = []
pdbl = PDBList()
PDBlist2 = ['2dd6', '1lbO', 'iee7']
for i in PDBlist2:
    ppdb0.append(pdbl.retrieve_pdb_file(i,pdir='.', file_format ='pdb'))
    ppdb1.append(PandasPdb().fetch_pdb(i))
```

It was working pretty well but after restart my computer now I am having this error:

```
Downloading PDB structure '2dd6'...
Desired structure doesn't exists
Downloading PDB structure '1lbO'...
Desired structure doesn't exists
HTTP Error 404
```

Does anybody get the same? can you tell me how can I fix this, please?
Pd: is the same if I use capital letters to write the protein accession number

Comment: `Error 404` means web paga doesn't exist. Maybe you could download it manually and install it. OR maybe server has problem and you should check code few hours later. OR they change pages on server and you have to install newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the pages
https://www.rcsb.org/structure/2DD6
and
https://www.rcsb.org/structure/1lbO
I can see: Protein 2DD6 does exist and returns a HTTP 200 result.
A protein with ID 1lbO just does not exist so I get a 404 (page not found).
And iee7 is not even a valid PDB ID as it does not start with a number. Protein 1EE7 does exist - Maybe a typo?

Comment: Hello Lydia. Thank you for your comment. I tried other sequences and it worked. You were right I just wrote those accession numbers wrong. Thank you for your help